# Get-Service in a script does not work when not logged onto server

Tags: windows, powershell, iis-7, windows-services

I wrote a script to check the IIS service status every 15 minutes on a web server.  I scheduled this script via Windows Task Scheduler.

When Im logged onto the server and manually run the script if functions coorectly.  When I am not logged onto the server and execute this via at batch script, the `Get-Service` query does not return `Running` for IIS even though it is indeed up and restarts the service.

Why would this script run differently when Im physically logged onto the server vs running as a scheduled task behind the scenes?

The script is called like this: `C:\Scripts\powershell.exe -File verify_status.ps1 [Service param]`

```
##############################
# Get service status
##############################
if($args[0] -ne $NULL){

    $serviceName = $args[0]
    $serverName = hostname

    $status = (Get-Service $serviceName).Status

    if ($status -ne "Running"){
        sendMail "$serviceName" "$serverName"
        Restart-Service $ServiceName
    }else{
            # Service is running, do nothing;
    }
}
```

=====================================

**EDIT** - The Get-Service returns a `NULL` when the script is run with no one logged on.  If that helps at all.

Comment: The scheduled task run with same credentials as you log on?

Comment: @Christian - Yes, it runs with my same credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things resolved this issue.  I think the main one was changing the `.bat` script calling the powershell script.

I went from:

```
C:\Scripts\powershell.exe -File verify_status.ps1 [Service param]
```

to

```
C:\Scripts\powershell.exe -File verify_status.ps1 "[Service param]"
```

The double quotes were necessary to pass the parameter correctly to the powershell script.

I also changed the following in the powershell script itself.  Im not sure if this was necessary but the combination of the two made this work:

```
$status = (Get-Service $serviceName).Status
```

to

```
$status = (Get-WmiObject -ComputerName SERVERNAME -Class Win32_Service -Filter "Name='$serviceName'").State
```

The `Windows Task Scheduler` now executes this script correctly and without error.